# Returning values from Service asynchronous method to Activity

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I have a Service class that I am using to make web service calls using Volley:

```
public class AccountService {
    public static void forgotPassword(Context c, String emailAddress) {

        String url = "myUrl";

        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // done
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });

        Volley.newRequestQueue(c).add(request);

    }

}
```

And I'm calling it from an Activity like this:

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private void submit() {
        accountService.forgotPassword();
    }
}
```

When the Volley request is finished, I want to update the UI in my activity. How can I do this considering it is an asynchronous request? Am I able to call a method from the AccountService class in my activity? Thanks for the help

Comment: use `onResponse()` to call your activity method to update about finished task!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a listener object to the AccountService and then send communication success or error to the activity.

Try as per below (you should not pass the layout to the AccountService which will create some unnecessary issues)

```
public class ForgotPasswordActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
                 implements View.OnClickListener,   
                                   AccountServiceCallback{

       private void submit() {
                AccountService.forgotPassword("email@123.com", this);
       }


       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }

      @Override
      public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
             // UPDATE UI as per on response requirement
      }

      @Override
      public void onErrorResponse(VollyError error) {
             // UPDATE UI as per response flow
      }
}

public class AccountService {

    public static void forgotPassword(Context c, String email, final    
                       AccountServiceCallback callback) {

           String url = "myUrl";

           JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                             // done
                             callback.onResponse(response);
                      }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                callback.onErrorResponse(error);
           }
       });

      Volley.newRequestQueue(c).add(request);

     }

   interface AccountServiceCallback {
       public void onResponse(JSONArray response);
       public void onErrorResponse(VollyError error);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Wow, very simple. Thanks a lot for the quick answer. Will try this out

Answer (score -1):

You will have to find a way to get the result of your background work back onto the main thread so it can make changes to the view hierarchy.  There are a LOT of ways to do this, and most of them are not really good.

But before you even do that, there are problems with your code.  First, if you are thinking you made an Android Service component, you didn't actually do that.  You made a class with the name AccountService, which does nothing special in the Android world.

Second, your call of forgotPassword() passes no arguments, but your definition of forgotPassword() in AccountService has a completely different signature.  This wouldn't compile.

You should probably start learning about Android-specific asynchronous programming patterns and develop a strategy for solving your problem before writing code, because you'll almost certainly do it wrong without understanding what you're doing first.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I trimmed down the method for simplicity sake; my code does compile. You only really pointed out what is wrong with my code and not much on how to fix it. "There are a LOT of ways to do this" - but you didn't list any. "start learning about Android-specific asynchronous programming" but gave no resources. You point out I didn't actually make a Service component - well, how do I do that?

Comment: I think a google search for "android asynchronous programming" would be a great place to start.

Comment: BTW, almost always people on SO want *more* code, not less.  It's an extremely common recurring theme.